# How to reduce the time it takes to speed up an object?

Tags: physics, box2d

I have a body that I am applying a force to every step. However, I it takes a significant amount of time for it to speed up, which I do not want. Is there some value I can adjust to help with this?

Comment: I just answered [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015489/box2d-how-to-speed-up-acceleration/19030418#19030418) over on SO... What happens with this double posting scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in "real life" physics to make it speed up faster (higher acceleration), increase the force or decrease the mass. You may be familiar with the common physics equation `F=MA`, you can also look at that as: `Acceleration=Force/Mass`.

So lowering the mass or increasing the force will change the acceleration. Where acceleration, of course, is the change in velocity over time, which is exactly what you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. This is rather obvious now that I think of it, but physics was never my strong subject